# Why is \newpage ignored sometimes ?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I have the following towards the end of an article. The bibliography is short (4 entries).

What's happening is that on the very last page of document I get the chart and immediately afterwards the References section, despite the `\newpage` directive. While I personally prefer everything on one page, I have a requirement to put the references on a different page. Is LaTeX ignoring `\newpage` because it finds plenty of space to use on that page? If so, I'm confused why it does so even when told explicitly to start a new page.

I cannot post the entire article so hopefully the excerpt below will be helpful.

```
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{my-image}
  \caption{caption here}\label{my-label}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
```

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Floating figures and tables can move past `\newpage`, so what is happening is that the `\newpage` does start a new page, then inserts the figure, then starts the references section.

You want `\clearpage`, which has the same effect as `\newpage` but restricts floats as well. If there are pending floats when `\clearpage` hits, a float page is created only after which the content will continue.

Comment: Moreover, if you're writing a document with the 'twoside' and 'openright' options (e.g. a book), you want to use \cleardoublepage

Comment: neither `\newpage` nor `\clearpage` nor `\cleardoublepage` work for me. Any ideas? I have lots of graphics and not much text in my document but latex float placement at the moment is really far off.

Comment: @holger I suggest searching through tex.sx for float placement help. If still in doubt ask a new question.

Comment: The error was that in the class that I used some package was loaded that made all floats appear at the very end of the page. (endfloat or something like that). Therefore all the other options did not work.

Comment: +1 Awesome, you saved me a lot of headache. Thank you, Will.

Answer (score 15):

For me works properly something like this, I force the creation of a new page with the invisible sign.

```
\clearpage
\newpage
\mbox{~}
\clearpage
\newpage
```

Comment: `\mbox{}` is sufficient

Comment: `\newpage` right after `\clearpage` does nothing.

Comment: I had the same problem -- I do NOT need "\mbox{~}'' but I do need ``\mbox{}'' as well as that "redundant'' \clearpage command.

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Thank you