# \newpage,\clearpage and \cleardoublepage not working

Tags: page-breaking

I'm trying to compile the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{textblock*}{125mm}(0mm,0mm)
  \noindent
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{front.jpg}
\end{textblock*}
\newpage
Hello!
\end{document}
```

I get the jpg image on the first page. But the second page with "Hello" comes over the first page itself. I tried `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\newpage` as per the following question:

[Why is \newpage ignored sometimes ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/why-is-newpage-ignored-sometimes)

But to no avail. Any suggestions so as to how to get a new page started after the first page?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It happens because `TeX` thinks the page is empty, so `\newpage` is ignored. Use `\null\newpage` instead. See section 2.2 of the [textpos package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) for details.

Comment: It is amazing how every problem has a not-for-newbies answer in TeX :/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (skips two pages) :

```
\phantom{p. 1}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{p. 2}
\clearpage
```

Answer (score 1):

The textblock is avoiding the newpage working.
This code works fine :

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\begin{document}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{front.jpg}
      \newpage
      Hello!
\end{document}
```

Why do you need it ?