# "Page intentionally left blank" with twoside openright

Tags: page-breaking, document-classes, blank-page

I'm using `twoside,openright` in my document class, and I'm wondering how to have "Page intentionally left blank" text on the pages that openright makes blank. I've seen people redefining `\cleardoublepage` however this looks like it only works if you're using `\cleardoublepage` explicitly in the document

EDIT Just found that that redefinition works fine actually! How would I add a page number into the following?

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside%
    \ifodd\c@page\else
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \hfill
    \begin{center}
    This page intentionally left blank.
    \end{center}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: and what's the problem with  using `\cleardoublepage` in a document ?

Comment: Becuase openright should automatically be creating those pages

Comment: May I refer this [previous](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65698/newpage-clearpage-and-cleardoublepage-not-working) answer ...

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}`-->`\thispagestyle{plain}`

Answer (score 2):

The following gives the expected result, use `\thispagestle{plain}` to get a pagenumber. Stolen from [How to make *intentionally left blank* pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-i-make-pages-which-were-intentionally-left-blank)

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside%
    \ifodd\c@page\else
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \hfill
    \begin{center}
    This page intentionally left blank.
    \end{center}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
```