# "This page intentionally left blank", but only in front matter

Tags: clearpage

I using the `book` class for my thesis and I want to insert a "This page intentionally left blank" message on the left pages when using `openright`. However, I only want to display this message in the `frontmatter` of my document, and use the headers set by `fancyhdr` in the `mainmatter` on an otherwise potantially empty page. I'm using the code below, adapted from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308522/156662) answer:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside%
    \ifodd\c@page\else
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \begin{center}
        This page intentionally left blank.
    \end{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{\MakeUppercase{My name}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{\MakeUppercase{\The title}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{The title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The first chapter}
\chapter{The second chapter}
\end{document}
```

I tried to put `\if@mainmatter` in different places in the definition of the `cleardoublepage` command, but I couldn't get it to work. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very close to what you had (and you probably attempted).  I was able to make `\if@mainmatter` work.  The other difference is that `\frontmatter` needed to come before `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[openright]{book}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage%
\if@twoside%
 \ifodd%
  \c@page%
 \else%
  \if@mainmatter%
   \hbox{}%
  \else%
   \vspace*{5cm}
   \begin{center}This page intentionally left blank.\end{center}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
  \fi%
  \newpage%
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi%
 \fi%
\fi%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{\MakeUppercase{My name}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{\MakeUppercase{\The title}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{The title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\chapter{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The first chapter}
\chapter{The second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility (but more work) would be to `\let\mainmattercleardoublepage=\cleardoublepage`, then do your redefinition, and redefine `\mainmatter` to also include `\let\cleardoublepage=\mainmattercleardoublepage`.

Answer (score 4):

Redefinition can be done inside a group that only contains the front matter:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{\MakeUppercase{My name}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{\MakeUppercase{The title}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{The title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside%
    \ifodd\c@page\else
    \vspace*{5cm}
    \begin{center}
        This page intentionally left blank.
    \end{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\chapter{Abstract}

\endgroup
\mainmatter
\chapter{The first chapter}
\chapter{The second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works after swapping `\endgroup` and `\mainmatter`. Otherwise, I don't get the message on the page after the abstract. I will wait a bit longer for an answer that changes the definition of the `\cleardoublepage` command and fits in the preamble. Otherwise I will accept your answer. Thanks!