# Adding ``This page was intentionally left blank.'' placeholder page in twoside document

Tags: blank-page

I wish to add placeholders into my disseration to ensure that all chapters begin on an odd page. These placeholders should contain ``This page was intentionally left blank.'' printed in the centre of the page. I'm using the document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
```

and within my latex code preamble I have placed the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        This page was intentionally left blank.
    \end{center}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

which I found on a previous post https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20410. However, this code snippet doesn't appear to have the desired outcome. I've also tried the hack [How do I make pages which were "intentionally left blank"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-i-make-pages-which-were-intentionally-left-blank) but this doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: .. to ensure that all chapters begin on an odd page ... Don't the book or scrbook classes do that automatically? What class are you using?

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Can you make a failing example and describe what is against your expectation?

Comment: @Ingmar - I'm using the twosided report class: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290802

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work, just had to change:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
```

to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
```

Comment: @Ingmar - many thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: the question was bumped to front page recently, OP may want to accept the answer if they're still active.

Comment: @user202729 -- "Last seen more than 2 years ago."