# Custom headers/footers and filler text position on "blank" left-hand page

Tags: header-footer, titles, geometry, book-design

**What I want:**

The title page of my report has custom margins to comply with my document's formatting guidelines. I use the package `geometry` for that, with the command `\newgeometry{}` for the title page.

Afterwards, I want my whole document to use custom `fancyhdr` headers and footers. Even blank left-hand pages created by the default argument `openright` must be numbered, including the first blank page immediately after the title (page 2).

I also want blank left-hand pages to have the mention "*this page intentionally left blank*" or something alike (most likely, it will be a decorative symbol); to do so, I use the solution described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290802/page-intentionally-left-blank-with-twoside-openright).

**My problem:**

Everything behaves as expected on blank left-hand pages in the middle of the document (for example, page 4 in the minimal working example below). However, page 2, just after the title, has two issues:

- The filler text is not centered
- The page number is missing

Using the package `showframe` I can see that the custom geometry of the title page is not applied to the blank page 2, so it looks like it might not be a case of the headers/footers being offset and pushed outside of the page.

[image: Correct left pages]
[image: Incorrect left page after custom geometry title page]

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

% HEADERS AND FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy} %for regular pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}} % for the first page of new chapters

% CSUTOM "BLANK" LEFT-HAND PAGES
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
This page intentionally left blank
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
This is the title page with custom margins.
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter*{Second chapter}
\lipsum[10-12]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restore the original geometry after the titlepage.

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
    This is the title page with custom margins.
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry % added <<<<<<<<
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had tried to add it before \end{titlepage} but it turns out it needed to be after that command...