# Comparison between \newpage, \clearpage and \pagebreak, etc.?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

> Can some experts give a short and succinct comparison between **\newpage, \clearpage, \cleardoublepage and \pagebreak, and other** related functions/commands (if there are some we should know)?

What I find to be related: [What is the difference between "Page Break" and "New Page"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/what-is-the-difference-between-page-break-and-new-page)

[Is it wrong to use \clearpage instead of \newpage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/is-it-wrong-to-use-clearpage-instead-of-newpage)

[Why is \newpage ignored sometimes ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/why-is-newpage-ignored-sometimes)

p.s. I do not find exactly the same questions -- although there are many related previous ones.

Thank you! Happy summer!

Comment: Consider accepting the excellent provided answer.

Answer (score 56):

`\newpage` is a low level command on which `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` are built upon. It ends the current paragraph (if not issued *between* paragraphs), fills the current page with white space and starts a new page.

`\clearpage` does something more, as it also flushes the float queues, producing pages of floats if necessary, then starts a new page.

`\cleardoublepage` is the same as `\clearpage`, but it also checks the number of the last ejected page; if the number is odd and `twosided` typesetting is in force, it fills another blank page so the new page to start on will be again odd-numbered.

The command `\pagebreak` is quite different from `\newpage` and its siblings described above.

If issued *inside* a paragraph, it will force a page break after the line in which it happens to fall when the paragraph is eventually typeset. It also issues ***no*** white space filling command, so the last line on the page will be at the bottom margin when `\flushbottom` is in force (for instance with `book` or generally with `twosided` documents).

If issued between paragraphs, it will force a page break *without filling*.

This command is useful in the last stage of document production: one can force a page break at a convenient spot for improving the typesetting of the next page. Clearly, the text should be in definitive form for this to be effective.

Note that `\pagebreak` has an optional argument, which can be a number among 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Issuing `\pagebreak[4]` is the same as `\pagebreak`, `\pagebreak[0]` just marks a point where a page break is possible (after the line it falls in). The other numbers mark a greater “desirability” of a page break.

Comment: Note that `\cleardoublepage` may be either completely blank or include a running head/page number, depending on the document class.