# How to put the title page on the second page?

Tags: margins, titles, book-design, layout, page

I know this isn't standard practice, but I need to put the *title page* of some special document **on the back of the first page** (i.e on the second page), so the extra white margin appears on the right side instead of the left part.  The first page should stay empty.  Here's a MWE to try:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{160, 180, 180}
\definecolor{andcolor}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup
    \pagecolor{backgroundcolor}
    \centering
    {\fontsize{68}{0}\selectfont{Some Big Title}} \\[0.6\baselineskip]
    \vfill
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
    \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
    \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\maintitle

\LARGE\raggedright

A section\dotfill iii

\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

Some comments\dotfill vii

\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

One more thing\dotfill ix

\vfill

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

So what commands should I add to this example to draw the title page on page 2 instead of page 1?

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to insert the empty page inside the environment `titlepage` like this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
~\newpage % <===========================================================
\thispagestyle{empty} % <===============================================
\setcounter{page}{1} % <================================================
```

With the following compilable TeX code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{1.5in}{1in}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{RGB}{160, 180, 180}
\definecolor{andcolor}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
\definecolor{subtitle}{RGB}{230, 255, 255}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\maintitle}{\begingroup
    \pagecolor{backgroundcolor}
    \centering
    {\fontsize{68}{0}\selectfont{Some Big Title}} \\[0.6\baselineskip]
    \vfill
\endgroup}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
~\newpage % <===========================================================
\thispagestyle{empty} % <===============================================
\setcounter{page}{1} % <================================================
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[line width = 1in,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (0.25in,0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (0.25in,-0.25in)$);
    \draw[line width = 0.25pt,color = black] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.25in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.25in,0.25in)$);
    \draw[line width = 1pt,color = white] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-0.5in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.5in,0.5in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\maintitle

\LARGE\raggedright

A section\dotfill iii

\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

Some comments\dotfill vii

\vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}

One more thing\dotfill ix

\vfill

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

you get the following second (even) page (first (odd) page is empty):

[image: second page, first page is empty]

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** I would just try ...

```
~ % added
\newpage % added
\begin{titlepage}
```

The `~` is invisible so that [`\newpage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497746) has something to do :).

**Update:** Does not work. I guess that the book class always wants to start with an odd page number for that title page. https://zhiganglu.com/post/latex-insert-blank-page/ seems to work but it will change the numbering (`\addtocounter{page}{-1}`). **The OP seems to be a bit angry so I just stop trying to help.**

---

**(2)** For your next question please understand that you provided way too much code, in my opinion, your problem boils down to:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
~
\newpage
\begin{titlepage}
MY TITL EPAGE
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Maybe have a look at [this excellent post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

---

**(3)** In addition, you have many questions with answers but you did not accept the answers. Please be nice and accept the answers that solved your problem.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work.  It just adds **two** pages before the title page, so it is back on an odd numbered page.  About (2) : I just asked one question.

Comment: @Cham Strange, maybe I made a mistake. What about **(3)**? **(2)** is not only about asking one question. It's about providing a generic version of your problem that does not include unnecessary code.

Comment: Obviously, your solution doesn't work at all, and it's not strange to me.  And (3) is irrelevant to the question here.

Comment: @Cham Not sure if you understand that **volunteers** make this site possible. I stop trying to help now. And I stand by **(2)**, your MWE can easily be made more minimal.

Comment: You can put `~\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}` before
`\begin{titlepage}`.

Comment: @user242026, this is almost working.  I'm getting a compilation error, while the preview shows the title page at the proper place (on page 2).  What is missing?  And I suggest you add your suggestion as an answer.