# Positioning images next to each other or stacking them with centered captions (Memoir class)

Tags: graphics, captions, memoir

**Problem:** I have groupings of images to be displayed together on a single page.  They are groups of two, three, four, or five. Some should be grouped/displayed horizontally on a single page with captions centered under each while others should be grouped/displayed vertically. For some groups the spacing should be very minimal but evident.

**Question:** How do I control the spacing or positioning of the images to get them next to each other as described?

**Example (with every package I'm using):**

```
% BEGIN PREAMBLE

\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{memoir}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{Some Images}
\makeoddhead{headings}{Some Images}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{\thepage}{}{}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

% END PREAMBLE

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{200pt}

\begin{center}
\Huge{\textbf{Some Images}}
\end{center}

\newpage

\vspace*{200pt}

\noindent Some introductory paragraph goes here.

\bigskip

A second introductory paragraph here.

\newpage

\vspace*{75pt}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.60]{image file name #1}
\captionof*{figure}{Image Name #1}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.90]{Image file name #2}
\captionof*{figure}{Image Name #2}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `subfigure` to organise your figures in the way you wish? (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest to load `blindtext` package and use `\Blinddocument` to test layouts. If you insert `\blindmathtrue`, the dummy text also contains equations.

You can easily distribute images across a page. Stack images line by line (without double empty lines) and latex will put everything next one another. Just make sure they fit the width.
Additionally, the tools from [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) help with captioning. The example below is based on `\subcaptionbox` but there are many other solutions.

A few options are possible when make horizontal groups. They lead to different arrangements. All the cases discussed below assume centring via `\centering` macro:

- don't append anything after an image and let LaTeX add space

```latex
\subcaptionbox{...}{...}
% ...
\subcaptionbox{...}{...}
```

If you want to increase the spacing, use `\hspace{}`, `\qquad` etc.

- distribute images with equal spacing before, after and between images; here you should append `\hfil` after every image but the last one

```latex
\subcaptionbox{...}{...}\hfil
\subcaptionbox{...}{...}\hfil
% ...
\subcaptionbox{...}{...}
```

- similarly to the previous case, distribute images with equal spacing but let images stick to margins; simply append `\hfill` instead of `\hfil`.

Below is a code with example. The line of `geometry` is only added for the demo, which produces a reference frame to show the current layout. `sidewaysfigure` (package `rotating`) is one way to render a content vertically. You should use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`. I'd also recommend on `figure` floats to let LaTeX optimise pages.

```latex
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt]{memoir}
% \usepackage{calc}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{microtype}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{Some Images}
\makeoddhead{headings}{Some Images}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{\thepage}{}{}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\pagestyle{headings}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
% END PREAMBLE

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}


%%% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{200pt}

\begin{center}
\Huge{\textbf{Some Images}}
\end{center}

\blindmathtrue\Blinddocument

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\linewidth}   % all immages in the group gain optioanal arguments 
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Image Name 1}{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\qquad
  \subcaptionbox{Image Name 2}{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
  \caption{Group of two images}\label{fig:group-imageb1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\linewidth}   % all immages in the group gain optioanal arguments 
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Image Name 1\label{fig:11}}{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\hfil
  \subcaptionbox{Image Name 2\label{fig:12}}{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hfil
  \subcaptionbox{Image Name 3\label{fig:13}}{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Group of three images}\label{fig:group-images2}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.18\linewidth}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Image 1\label{fig:21}}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 2\label{fig:22}}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 3\label{fig:23}}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 4\label{fig:24}}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 5\label{fig:25}}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
  \caption{Group of five images}\label{fig:group-images-3}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[tbh]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.14\linewidth}
  \captionsetup{position=bottom,belowskip=3ex}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Image 1}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 2}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 3}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 4}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 5}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 6}{\includegraphics{example-image}}
  \par
  \subcaptionbox{Image 7}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 8}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 9}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 10}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 11}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 12}{\includegraphics{example-image}}
  \par
  \subcaptionbox{Image 13}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 14}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 15}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 16}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 17}{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Image 18}{\includegraphics{example-image}}
  \caption{Grid of images}\label{fig:grid-images}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

Reference: figure~\ref{fig:11} and figure~\ref{fig:23}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\clearpage` and not `\newpage`?

Comment: It does more than just page break. Here's a good explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497776/31283

Comment: Why `\centering` and not the center environment as in my original code?

Comment: It doesn't mean you should not use `center` environment at all; `center` adds some extra spacing around it, so it has its use cases. `\centering` is barely a switch meaning that is everything in the same scope onward will be centred. Since each float environment, s.a. `figure` and `table`, also adds spacing, you should just use `\centering` in those cases.